# Change font width in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I trying to use plt.text to plot letters that are variously stretched or squeezed in the horizontal direction. I thought the 'stretch' option would do that, but it doesn't change anything:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.text(1,1, 'A', stretch=100)

plt.show()
```

It doesn't seem to matter what value I use for stretch, the result always looks the same.

Answer (score 4):

I tried specifying the stretch using `mpl.rcParams['font.stretch'] = 1000` but as per the [official docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), it seems `font.stretch` is not yet implemented (emphasis mine):

> The font.stretch property has 11 values: ultra-condensed, extra-condensed, condensed, semi-condensed, normal, semi-expanded, expanded, extra-expanded, ultra-expanded, wider, and narrower.  **This property is not currently implemented.**

Comment: I tried such code `plt.rcParams['font.stretch'] = 1000; plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'ABC')` but it seems font is not stretched (doesn't change width), even if I change 1000->50. Maybe we need somehow to load some stretchable font before? Do you know what free fonts are stretchable?