# Setting a font from .otf file as standard in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

On Ubuntu 20.04 I downloaded a new font to `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Helvetica_Neue_LT_Pro/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn.otf`.

The font shows up in the Ubuntu font manager:

[image: helvetica list in Ubuntu font manager]

I can use it in matplotlib like this:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

fpath = "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Helvetica_Neue_LT_Pro/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn.otf"

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath)
ax.set_title("Helvetica Test", fontproperties=prop)

plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image: the new font works]

But this is annoying for my script with many figures. How can I set this font globally? This does not work:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "Helvetica Neue LT Pro, 57 Condensed"

ax.set_title("Helvetica Test")

plt.show()
```

There is no error or warning, but the result is:

[image]

Obviously the standard font is used here.

Edit: Thanks to tomjn I had a look at the fontlist at `/home/nettef/.cache/matplotlib/fontlist-v330.json`. The font is listed here as:

```
  {
    "fname": "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Helvetica_Neue_LT_Pro/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn.otf",
    "name": "Helvetica Neue LT Pro",
    "style": "normal",
    "variant": "normal",
    "weight": 400,
    "stretch": "condensed",
    "size": "scalable",
    "__class__": "FontEntry"
  },
```

But there are 50 others with the field `"name": "Helvetica Neue LT Pro"`. Could this be the central problem? I can actually manually change the name to `"name": "Helvetica Neue LT Pro Condensed"` and then set it globally like this:

```
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Helvetica Neue LT Pro Condensed"
```

This seems like a bad solution though since the fontlist is apparently auto generated and could break my script at any time.

Comment: You might need to rebuild your font cache. Either run `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()` or delete you `fontlist` cache files (something like `~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache`).

Comment: @tomjn Thanks. The first results in an error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.font_manager' has no attribute '_rebuild'`. I found and deleted the file `/home/nettef/.cache/matplotlib/fontlist-v330.json` but nothing changed in the above results.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is very useful! I think you want

```py
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "sans-serif"
plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = ["Helvetica Neue LT Pro"] + plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"]
plt.rcParams["font.stretch"] = "condensed"  # This is probably the key setting!
```

[You could put these in an rcfile too for convenience](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style)

Comment: It does not work, but it may work in the future! The stretch parameter is apparently yet to be implemented. See this question which I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56316728/5522601